# Invalid object name 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES' with Spring Boot WS and JDBC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sql-server-2008, jdbc

The server is a SQL Server 2008 , the run return this exception

```
09:00:51.579 [task-1] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl - Could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:792) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:689) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerStatement.java:616) ~[sqljdbc4-4.0.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeQuery(ProxyStatement.java:111) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:?]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.sequenceInformationList(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:403) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:268) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1245) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) [?:?]
```

This is the pom.xml, i'm using the JDBC official of Microsoft, i tried also with 6.2 without effects.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal</groupId>
        <artifactId>resolver</artifactId>
        <version>20050927</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- exclude logback , add log4j2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- asynchronous loggers -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
        <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- other dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.22.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <enableDirtyTracking>true</enableDirtyTracking>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                <sourceType>wsdl</sourceType>
                <sources>
                    <source>
                        ${project.basedir}/PATH/file.wsdl
                    </source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The settings are in .properties.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://URL:1433;databaseName=DB;
spring.datasource.username=USERNAME
spring.datasource.password=PASSWORD
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.database=sql_server
spring.jpa.hibernate.dll-auto=update
useServerPrepStmts=true
```

I tried with `spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect` but no result.

Example of MODEL

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "NAME_TABLE", catalog = "NAME_DB", schema = "DBO")
public class nameClass implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "secondField")
    private String secondField;
//CONSTRUCTOR
//GETTER AND SETTER
}
```

The database is not normalized, the table havent primary key and foreign key.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Is it full stack trace?

Comment: I see that you use `hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final` (from your stack trace), but from your `pom.xml` I see that you use `5.4.4.Final`. It is a bad idea to mix version up.

Comment: @SternK yes is the full trace, i missed last lines, i modified the topic with full pom and full trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was the string `spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect`
is changed to

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following :

1) Make sure that you are connected to the correct server and database.

2) user has the privileges to connected database.

```
sql : GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::[Name of Schema] TO [Name of user]
```

If connected to correct database, see if the table is present. If it is, try to refresh the tables

Comment: Yes, i have the db with the same user in Datagrip, in Information_Schema there isnt Sequences, it doesnt exist (i read around that before of 2012 is normal). In the beginning i had a problem with the connection, because java cant create the tunnel ssl with the db, i fixed following same topic on stackoverflow, i deleted 3ds from disabledalgorithm of java.securty, but now i have this exception.

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding, your code problem at @generatedValue annotation do one thing run your code without @GeneratedValue. if it runs fine, go with @GeneratedValue articles once

Comment: I tried removing -@Id and -@GeneratedValue, but dont work.

Comment: dont remove -@Id, remove only -@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)